# State persistence in react-query-builder

Tags: reactjs, query-builder

I'm using react-query-builder for my search page, I want to maintain the query state on the UI in the query builder.
Currently when the query gets completed and results are displayed on the next page, when we navigate back to the search page, the query is getting cleared
How can maintain the state of the query in query  builder?

I tried using defualtQuery in the props but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Maintainer of `react-querybuilder` here. This sounds more like a general state persistence problem than anything to do with RQB specifically. You might need to use `localStorage` or something like that. Can you provide a repo or codesandbox that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hi @JakeBoone, I did some research and found out that using "Import JsonLogic" my issue can be resolved, but the "parseJsonLogic" method is not working when I'm trying to turn a string query into builder query. Can you help?

I'm using "setState" to change the query field.

setQuery(parseJsonLogic(JSON.stringify(qeury1)));

Comment: Can you set up a CodeSandbox or StackBlitz or something to demonstrate the issue? Also probably better to talk through this in the `react-querybuilder` GitHub repo discussions. https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder